# Phantom unknown record property name causing 500 error

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I am getting this error on a form load:

> Unknown record property / related component "title" on "Flipbook"

The thing is...I have no idea where "title" is coming from. I have set it up as `career_title` in the schema and database. The model is built and the base classes are correct.

Here is my action:

```
 public function executeEdit(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
      if (get_class($this->getRoute()) == 'sfDoctrineRoute') {
        /* edit action */
        $flipbook = $this->getRoute()->getObject();     
      }
      else {
        /* add action */
        $flipbook = new Flipbook();
      }

      $this->form = new FlipbookForm($flipbook);

      if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $this->form->bind($request->getParameter('flipbook'));
        if ($this->form->isValid()) {           
            $this->form->save();
            $this->getUser()->setFlash('message_success', 'Flipbook saved');
            return $this->redirect('@flipbook_edit?id=' . 
                    $this->form->getObject()->get('id') . 
                    ($request->getParameter('preview') ? '&preview=1' : ''));       
                }
              }
          }
```

If I remove the `$flipbook` variable from  `$this->form = new FlipbookForm($flipbook);`, I get a successfully rendered form, but I need the object data to repopulate the input fields.

I just have no idea why it is finding "title" on the object. I do not have that referenced anywhere (I don't think). Any ideas? Typos? Suggestions?

Let me know if I need to provide further code.

Here is the **yml schema** for the added class:

```
     Generic:
          actAs: [ Timestampable ]
          columns:
            updated_by: { type: integer }
            created_by: { type: integer }
            published: { type: boolean, default: 0 }
          relations:
            creator:
              class: sfGuardUser
              foreignAlias: created_users
              local: created_by
              onDelete: "SET NULL"
            last_updater:
              class: sfGuardUser
              foreignAlias: updated_users
              local: updated_by
              onDelete: "SET NULL"

            flipbook:
              url:  /flipbook
              param: { module:

    Flipbook:
      tableName: flipbook
      inheritance:
        extends: Generic
        type: concrete
      columns:
        career_title: { type: string(255) }
        career_associations: { type: clob }
        skills: { type: string(255) }
        skills_associations: { type: clob }
        program: { type: string(255) }
        program_associations: { type: clob }
        draft_id: { type: integer(10) }
```

And finally the **template** if you need it:

```
<?php echo $form->renderFormTag(url_for($form->getObject()->isNew() ? '@flipbook_add' : ('@flipbook_edit?id=' . $form->getObject()->get('id'))), array('method' => 'post', 'id' => 'edit_form', 'name' => 'edit_form', 'class' => 'generic_form job_form')) ?>
  <?php echo $form['id'] ?>
  <div class="content-box">
    <div class="box-body">
      <div class="box-header clear">
        <h2>Flipbook</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="box-wrap clear"  style="display: block;">
        <?php echo $form ?>
      </div><!-- end of box-wrap -->
    </div> <!-- end of box-body -->
  </div>

  <div class="buttons_row right main_actions">
    <?php include_partial('global/apply_changes_button', array('form' => $form)) ?>
    <?php include_partial('global/publish_button', array('form' => $form)) ?>
  </div>
</form>

<?php include_partial('global/preview', array('form' => $form)) ?>
```

**Routing**:

```
 flipbook, action: index }
    flipbook_add:
      url:   /flipbook/add
      param: { module: flipbook, action: edit }
    flipbook_edit:
      url:   /flipbook/edit/:id
      param: { module: flipbook, action: edit }
      param: { module: flipbook, action: edit }
      class: sfDoctrineRoute
      options: { model: Flipbook, type: object }
      requirements:
        id: \d+
        sf_method: [get, post]
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
stack trace at () in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Record/Filter/Standard.php line 55 ...

    public function filterGet(Doctrine_Record $record, $name)
    {
      throw new Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException(sprintf('Unknown record property
       / related component "%s" on "%s"', $name, get_class($record)));
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

This is still not really resolved so I would like to keep it open for a bit to see if anyone can diagnose the problem. The way I got around it was to change `career_title` to `title` in the schema. I Rebuilt the model and forms and all works fine. Any further instruction on why this is happening would be beneficial to the cause.

Comment: Can you post your route, and trace for this error ?

Comment: Yes. All caches have been cleared.

Comment: Do you have a title field in "Generic"?

Comment: I added the Generic schema also. No title mentioned here either.

Comment: Is this just a copy paste error in your schema yml?:             flipbook:
              url:  /flipbook
              param: { module:

Comment: Can you explain a little further? You said schema, but what you wrote is from routing. Can you see an error directly? If so, point it out?

Comment: Can you post your `FlipbookForm` class? Is there any widget added as `title`?